# How to prove: a quadratic form with a matrix $ B = CC^T $ is positive defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let a matrix $ C \in \Bbb K^{n \mathtt x n} : det(c) \ne 0 $ (K is any field - C or R)
$ \Rightarrow $ a quadratic form with a matrix $ B = CC^T $ is positive defined one. How to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $x^TBx=x^TCC^Tx=(C^Tx)^T(C^Tx)\ge 0$, and we have equality iff $x=0$.

Comment: generally speaking Cx is not always > 0; Is it correct to say, that the construction $ (C^Tx)^T*(C^Tx) ~ (Cx)^2 $ like a square power is always positive?

Comment: @so-olitary
it is, $C^Tx$ is just a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ so $(C^Tx)^T(C^Tx)$ is just the innerproduct, which is always $\ge 0$ if the two entries are the same.

Comment: @so-olitary be careful when defining this over $\Bbb C$, here you will need to consider $B=CC^*$ for the result to always hold, where $C^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $C$.

Comment: In the task a field do not defined precisely. OK. I'll take a notice.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix} c_{11} & c_{12} & \cdots &c_{1n}\\
c_{21} & c_{22} & \cdots & c_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_{n1} & c_{n2} & \cdots & c_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then,
$$
x'C= \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i1}& \sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i2}&\cdots &\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{in}\end{pmatrix}
$$
so it follows that
$$
x'CC'x= \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i1}& \sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i2}&\cdots &\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{in}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i1}\\ \sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i2}\\\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{in}\end{pmatrix}\\=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i1}\right)^2+ \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{i2}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ic_{in}\right)^2\\=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ic_{ij}\right)^2>0.
$$
The inequality is quite obvious from the fact that we have a sum of squares in conjunction with the non-zero determinant, as this rules out the positive semi-definite case (allowing a zero determinant would mean it'd be possible for $C$ to be a zero matrix). In other words, since $x$ is by definition non-zero the sum of squares would be equal to zero if and only if $C$ was a zero matrix, but since its determinant is non-zero we know that at least $n$ elements are non-zero. Hence, their squares are positive.

Comment: Thank you for this full-scale answer!